# Music software. Simultaneous start

Tags: software

I am running cool edit pro 2 (oldskool) and fruity loops pro 12 WITH WINDOWS 10
. How do I get the two programs to start to play simultaneously? I'd like to be able to put fruity loops into a line of the cool edit pro mixer, so it runs as a line of the session, and can be edited as part of the session in cool edit from fruity loops.

Comment: You could improve this question by letting people know which operating system you're using. Probably Windows or MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

In windows there is a protocol called [Rewire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReWire_(software_protocol)) by [Propellerhead](https://www.propellerheads.se/) ( the authors of Reason ). Many Daw are compatible with such protocol, may be you need to do some further search on the documentation of both software you are using in order to see if they can be connected this way.